# Postgres: how to select special rows within joined tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

As an example I have this code:

```
select src_table.name, src_table.email, src_table.number
from employees as src_table
cross join users as dst_table
where src_table.email = dst_table.email
    or src_table.name = dst_table.name
```

It outputs:

```
name     email          number
sam    | qwe@bcv.com  | null
john   | null         | +14823
jack   | edb@abc.com  | null
alex   | cdb@dbc.co   | null
```

But there're matching rows in the dst_table (same structure and needed fields can be identified by the unique name), there're numbers for 1st, 3rd and 4th rows, email for 2nd row and so on. How do I write the code so it outputs the nonull (if it exists; else it leaves null) cell's value?
I need output rows to be like "nonull name | nonull email | nonull number" or "nonull name | nonull or null email | null or nonull number" (if nonull value doesn't exist in both tables).

 My actual code is:

```
select src_table.id as src_id, dst_table.id as dst_id,
    src_table.name, src_table.middle, src_table.surname,
    src_table.mobile_phone,
    src_table.email,
    src_table.position
from employees as src_table
cross join users as dst_table
where src_table.email = dst_table.email
    or (src_table.name = dst_table.name
        and src_table.surname = dst_table.surname)
    or (src_table.name = dst_table.name
        and src_table.surname = dst_table.surname)
```

If 1st table looks like the one I printed after "It outputs:" and the second is

```
name     email          number
sam    | null         | +10678
john   | yxz@foo.bar  | null
jack   | null         | +57656
alex   | null         | +82345
```

I expect result to be:

```
name     email          number
sam    | qwe@bcv.com  | +10678
john   | yxz@foo.bar  | +14823
jack   | edb@abc.com  | +57656
alex   | cdb@dbc.co   | +82345
```

Comment: Why do you disguise an inner join in with `cross join`? (Or the other way round: why use `cross join` if you actually want an `inner join`?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can't have the condition after ```on``` in my case (the example code isn't my real one), also inner join leaves only rows that exist in both tables but I want to use row's values that exist in one and don't exist in another table.

Comment: Sure you can have the condition after the `ON`. And the way you have written it, it's just a regular inner join and equivalent to `from employees as src_table join users as dst_table on src_table.email = dst_table.email or ...` - you probably just want a a left join or maybe even a full outer join `from employees full join users ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I make it inner and ```on email = another email``` it won't output rows where email is null, in my code after the ```cross join``` I have ```where src_table.email = dst_table.email or (src_table.name = dst_table.name and src_table.surname = dst_table.surname) or (src_table.name = dst_table.name and src_table.surname = dst_table.surname)```

Comment: Again: your current "cross join" is exactly the same as an inner join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but output results are greatly dissimilar

Comment: Extended the question with my code

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. I can't understand the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

@amshinski If I right understand your question, you need join tables by email, but if email are null on both sides, join by name. If name are null on both sides then join by surname, etc.
You can join by case

```
select *
  from employees as src
  join users as dst
    on case
         when src.email is not null or dst.email is not null then
           src.email = dst.email
         when src.name is not null or dst.name is not null then
           src.name = dst.name
         when src.surname is not null or dst.surname is not null then
           src.surname = dst.surname
       end
```

Comment: This is a good guess. Maybe the query should use `AND` instead of `OR`, but it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Actually it gives the same result as the cross join. I want output to be same as the output I told about in my question. If any cell is not null in any table then it's value is used for the output.

Comment: Ok, if you need to output first nonnull value from ona of the table try to add in select section: SELECT COALESCE(src.name, dst.name) as name, COALESCE(src.email, dst.email), ....

Comment: Oh seems that's what I need. Gonna try